# Solr DIH -- How to handle deleted documents?

Tags: lucene, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm playing around with a Solr-powered search for my webapp, and I figured it'd be best to use the DataImportHandler to handle syncing with the app via the database.  I like the elegance of just checking the `last_updated_date` field.  Good stuff.  However, I don't know how to handle deleting documents with this approach.  The way I see it, I've got 2 choices.  I could either send an explicit message to Solr from the client when a document is deleted, or I could add a "deleted" flag and leave the object in the database, so that Solr will notice that the document has changed and is now "deleted."  I could add a query filter that would disregard results with the deleted flag, but it seems inefficient to include all the deleted documents in the Lucene index.  What do other folks do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

These are your options:

- Use [DIH special commands](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands) $deleteDocById or $deleteDocByQuery (requires Solr 1.4+)
- Use the [clean parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands) of DIH to delete the whole index before importing.
- Use [preImportDeleteQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Schema_for_the_data_config) to define what's going to be cleaned up before importing. (requires Solr 1.4+)
- Use database triggers instead of DIH to manage updating the index.
- If you're using some sort of ORM use its interception capabilities instead of DIH. For example you can  use [hibernate events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events) to update the index on update, insert or delete.

Comment: That's a great list!  I'm still using 1.3, but that's a convincing reason to look into switching.

Comment: yeah, Solr 1.4 just went RC, final release is imminent.

Comment: Hi Mauricio,  are there any good examples how to use  preImportDeleteQuery when doing delta import on deleted documents?

Comment: Are there illustrations about how to use special commands? Do they have to be added to row using script?

Answer (score 2):

I like to have a "deleted" flag so I don't actually delete my data!  Depends on how paranoid you are.  I like Mauricio's suggestions...