# Solr how to remove physically deleted documents with DataImportHandler

Tags: lucene, solr, solrj, dataimporthandler, dih

I've read solr wiki and I know it is possible to use deletedPkQuery to remove the documents which deleted logically, but how to remove physically deleted documents with DataImportHandler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr DIH -- How to handle deleted documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555610/solr-dih-how-to-handle-deleted-documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by optimizing the index. Send an optimize request to Solr as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22). But beware, that optimizing the index means re-writing the index. Unless you have substantial number of deleted documents in the index, the overhead of optimizing can be quite high.