# Using Solr with MySQL

Tags: mysql, solr, faceted-search

I was browsing some questions here concerning MySQL and faceted searches and I saw one response that suggested the use of Solr.

In my MySQL database, I have many tables for products, suppliers, messages, users, etc - all interconnected. How would I use Solr to do faceted searches for products? From what I understand, I'd have to keep feeding Solr product data from MySQL - but how do I deal with indexing the data? Do index right after adding a new product? Do I batch index? How do I deal with Solr accurately representing data that is found in my MySQL database? (inserts, deletes, etc)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language and framework is your application built in? There are a lot of good Solr clients out there (e.g. Sunspot for Ruby apps) which can handle this kind of denormalizing and updating pretty transparently.

Comment: I'm currently using the CodeIgniter framework in PHP. Anything you could suggest me?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [data import handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler). Apart from batch update you can also trigger update by calling [update request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section). You would have to call it from your application but you can also create your own custom update request handler that would fit your needs.

Comment: How do I deal with deletes? From what I understood the data import handler deals mostly with inserts and updates. Thanks.

Comment: Check this for handling deletes in Solr. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555610/solr-dih-how-to-handle-deleted-documents

Comment: Add, update and delete is handled by update handler. Action depend on XML message sent. Check this resource: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_by_ID_and_by_Query. In extreme case you could write store procedure that would be attached to trigger on insert/update/delete on you DB table. However if there is application on top of you DB I would go with baking index maintenance logic into it.

Comment: Mind you, if you have big indexes which under heavy use you might consider going multi-core. In this scenario, you allow searchin on one core while building/updating second one. Once happy, or in given time intervals, you could swap secondary for main and start building main (for example batch update with data import handler). http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP

Answer (score 0):

If using data import handler, use the [delta import command](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command).

Comment: Please see my question in the comments of Jarekrozanski's response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLR is a JAVA application but you can access it using any language that provides HTTP GET/POST functionality.

for your need you should refer to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler
but before jumping on the Indexing part go through the tutorial at lucene.apache.org /solr /tutorial.html