# Update or delete data from Solr index?

Tags: php, mysql, search, solr

We have a php-application, which have a huge Mysql database and search index by Solr (with SolrPhpClient).

Before updating our index (via Cron), we deleting all items, which are not in the stock at the moment. And only than we selecting items from Mysql (in stock) and add this data to Solr.

I have an idea, that existing way of updating our search index is too expensive for app performance. In fact we reindex all this items (we use some filters in schema for russian word stemming, lower-case and so on...), instead of leaving out-of-stock items in index with flag (inStock=1).

In the future, I suppose, we'll have more than 100 000 position (maybe more) in index. So this way of updating would make our index too slow and server load too high.

Could you tell me your ideas about this problem from the positions of updating index and selecting data from it?

Thank for your attention...

Comment: What's "100 000 position"? Do you mean 100000 documents in the index?

Comment: Please see if the answer of this question helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555610/solr-dih-how-to-handle-deleted-documents

Comment: 2 Mauricio - Yes, each row in the importing mysql table is a one document in our Solr index.

Comment: 2 Shashikant - Thanks for link, I haven't found it before asking in stackoverflow's search issue. The problem is that we don't using DIH for import now - just a php-script. Can I make changes with DIH in mysql data after importing (It's about the success-import flags in mysql tables)? Are DIH is more efficient than php-script (It's logic: quering non actual data from musql - deleting it from the Solr index - quering actual data - adding (updating) it to the index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps by tuning your deletion you could get better performance.  Here's the pseudo-code:

- Remove only items that are "out of stock" AND in the Solr index
- Add/Update only items "in stock" but either do not exist in Solr OR the inventory count is wrong.

This way you are not re-indexing every single document every time, but only those that need updating.

Comment: But which way is better for performanсe of indexing and making search queries? To clean all the index from out of stock positions or leaving this documents in index with flag?

Comment: You'll need to test--it will vary based on the size and number of your documents.  Like I said, it *may* give better performance but the only way will be to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Solr's DIH is a good solution as you probably will end up writing a lot of boiler-plate code with PHP that is already available with DIH. While, I cannot comment specifically about efficiency of DIH vs your own custom code, my experience is, DIH does its job well. 100K documents (assuming they are not huge documents), isn't really big. I have seen Solr handle millions of documents without much effort.

I don't see need to have a "import-success" flag in DB. Solr maintains the state by itself.

You need to ensure that there is an additional field in your table that has update timestamp and delete are soft-deletes. Solr will use this timestamp to figure out the delta to be imported. Soft-delete flag will be used to remove documents that have been deleted.